# $3\times 3$ seats need to be taken this way.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have 9 seats named like this:

[image]

Seats $b_i$ can be taken if $a_i$’s are already taken. And $c_i$’s can be taken if $b_i$’s are taken.

The question is in how many ways can 9 individuals take these seats?

Here is what I think this number should be:

$\dfrac{9!}{2^3\cdot 2^3}=5670.$

Comment: Isn't this just $6^3$  ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think the answer is that?  Are you sure you don't want a $3^3$ term in the denominator instead of one of those $2^3$?

Comment: @Nate I think you're right. It must be $\frac{9!}{2^3\cdot 3^3}$ because of the third row.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is how I am interpreting the problem: The people come in in some fixed order and sit down one at a time.  The rule is that seat $b_i$ can't be filled until seat $a_i$ is, for the same index $i$.  Similarly seat $c_i$ can't be filled until seat $b_i$ is, again for the same index.  So for example seat $c_2$ can't be filled unless both seats $a_2$ and $b_2$ have already been filled, but doesn't care what is happening with any of the other seats.

If this is the correct interpretation then this problem is just a question of counting standard young tableux of a certain skew shape consisting of three horizontal strips that do not share any columns. Note that we do not want the  $3\times 3$ grid as under this interpretation the boxes in a vertical column don't interact.  Now the hook length formula gives us the answer $\frac{9!}{2^3\cdot 3^3}$.